# Pass parameters from html directive to controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to pass an argument from an html directive to a controller
Example:

Directive:

```
angular.module('app')
   .directive('helloWorld', function () {
  return {
      replace: false,
      restrict: 'AE',
      templateUrl: "./views/templates/helloWorld.html" 
  }
});
```

helloWorld.html:

```
<body ng-app="app" >
<div ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">
{{ welcome }}
</div>
```

hello.html:

```
<body ng-app="app">
<hello-world/>
</body>
```

HelloWorldCtrl:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('HomeWorldCtrl', function ($scope, ) {

    $scope.welcome = "Welcome"

    };
})
```

Can I specify a parameter in hello.html e.g.

```
<hello-world param="param1"/>
```

That is being passed into the controller?
So in the HomeWorldCtrl I can check the value of the parameter?
Are there any better alternatives to achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function(){
return {
  restrict:'E',
  scope: {
     param: '@'
  },
  template:'<div class="param"><h2>{{param}}</h3></div>'
};
});

// you have options to choose from

//= is two-way binding
//@ simply reads the value (one-way binding)
//& is used to bind functions

<hello-world="someParam"></hello-world>
//    for the scope definition:

scope: {
title: '@helloWorld'
}
The usage in the template will remain the same

<hello-world param="someParam"></hello-world>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this.Will the above suggestion pass the someParam to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

If you isn't use isolated scope (scope: {someparam: ""}), then you may use any $scope properties in the directive template without changing anything:

```
$scope.param = "new param value";
..
return {
  ..
  ,template: "<param>{{param}}</param>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

directive

```
   return {
      replace: false,
      restrict: 'AE',
      templateUrl: "./views/templates/PatientSearchEdit.html",
      scope: {
          param: '@'
      }
  }
```

controller

```
console.log($scope.param);
```

Logs indeed the value specified.
Thanks you very much!